# exception when running decoding program

Tags: java

I have a code to decode a string as follows:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String base64="anybase64value"       
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);
    String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    String testFileName = "/tmp/" + "base64.xlsx";

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(testFileName));
    IOUtils.write(bytes, fos);
    System.out.println("Wrote " + bytes.length + " bytes to: " + testFileName);
}
```

but when I run it throws me an error :

```
The method write(byte[], OutputStream) in the type IOUtils is not applicable for the arguments (byte[], File)
The method close() is undefined for the type File
```

Comment: What is the `IOUtils` class? Is it from Apache Commons? Do you get an exception or a compile error? And at which line did it occur?

Comment: Your program doesn't seem to match the error message you provided. You aren't even calling `close` anywhere.

Comment: Strange. Looking at this code it seems that the error you get is not caused by these lines : i confirm that your fos IS NOT a file ;)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're trying to call the method `write` in `sun.misc.IOUtils`, in rt.jar. You need to use import `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`. Probably wrong import.